# How to mock an object using jest , object is from CDN link

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, logging, mocking, jestjs

I managed to use an object(to log telemetry) from CDN link in the actual application but unfortunately my jest tests failed. Is there a way to mock this object or is there a way to skip telemetry code (don't execute those lines of code) if we are just running tests?

declare const oneDS: any;
let logger = new oneDS.ApplicationInsights(); // Works in usual application but fails for jest tests

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code can be skipped only if it was written with this intent, e.g.:

```
let logger;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  logger =  new oneDS.ApplicationInsights();
} else {
  logger = /* dummy implementation */
}
```

It can be mocked in tests as any other global variable:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  global.oneDS = {
    ApplicationInsights: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(/* dummy implementation */)
  };
});
```